# Boxfuse with Jhipster Deployment

Tags: liquibase, cloudcaptain

When upgrading my jhipster app to version 2.0 from 1.0 using Boxfuse  , I am getting `Liquibase checksum invalid error` . However I have changed nothing in the database .

Also, this happens only in prod mode and app runs fine in dev mode. How can I resolve this issue . Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with how jhipster uses Liquibase, but basically what you need to do is get liquibase to run the changelogsync command to get the changeset checksums updated.