# Update production database : jhipster

Tags: liquibase, cloudcaptain

I am having hard time understanding how Liquibase works with jhipster. I am using Boxfuse to deploy jar file to AWS. Now , since my application is evolving continuously I need to add/drop columns/tables every week.

Application works fine for the first time when I deploy it for the first time , Also it works fine when there is no change in the Database schema only the change in code. Now , I need to add column to database. I used mvn liquibase:update command wit the changesets containing the respective changes in the master.xml. Even the changes are applied to the database. I confirmed them.

Now, when I deploy the updated jar with the changes , It gives error and is unable to deploy. Also, boxfuse console does not show any specific error . It just says that failed to upload.

Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45951932/boxfuse-with-jhipster-deployment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boxfuse with Jhipster Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45951932/boxfuse-with-jhipster-deployment)